# What is the default response timeout in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone help to know about default response time in JMeter if we do not set any timeout in 'HTTP request' sampler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It defaults to `0` (no timeout)

The recommended way of setting the timeout is using GUI.

If for some reason it doesn't play for you you can use the following properties:

- *user.properties* file:

  - `httpclient.timeout`
- *httpclient.parameters* file:

  - `http.socket.timeout$Integer`

Both files live under JMeter's "bin" folder, JMeter restart is required to pick the properties up after the change.

References:

- [Timeouts for http requests](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Timeouts-for-http-requests-td5718438.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply Dmitri. For some reasons, my Jmeter 20 users test hangs at some point. We checked it in monitoring tool, but the response was sending back later in 2 mins. But JMeter execution hangs. Could you please tell me what could be the reason for test hung?

Comment: Normally you can find all the troubleshooting information in the *jmeter.log* file. If there is something like "OutOfMemory" there - your approach of running JMeter test is wrong, check [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#best_practices) and [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) articles for recommendations