# NoHttpResponseException but no response timeout set

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We have a long running request we're receiving a `NoHttpResponseException` on but we haven't set a response timeout so it [should wait indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40524906/185123), right? I've also checked the *user.properties* & *httpclient.parameters* files and I don't see any values set there either.

> 2021-02-12 12:20:12,278 ERROR o.a.j.a.J.Our custom JSR 223 Assertion: expected
> JSON Response: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: our.server.com:443 failed to respond
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
> at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:930)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1270)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

### [image: jmeter HTTP request screenshot]

[image: jmeter http request defaults screenshot]

JMeter version 5.3

Answer (score 0):

> it should wait indefinitely, right?

not really, if not set it goes for the underlying platform defaults.

For Windows it's 72 seconds for establishing the connection and 120 seconds for the response, controllable though, see [TCP/IP Configuration Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc739819(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

So you cannot disable the timeout, but you can set it to a very high value like [2147483647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)

If you want to apply the setting to all HTTP Request samplers from a single place - set the response timeout under [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)

Comment: Except that the response is not timing out at 120 secs so it doesn’t seem to be Windows TCP/IP defaults causing the exception