# Jmeter is throwing Non HTTP response code

Tags: jmeter

I am getting the below error message from Jmeter v5.4.3 (after all the users ramped up) in the middle of the test:

```
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Operation timed out
```

I am getting it most of the times I run it. Any suggestions? Connect Timeout limits are already set in HTTP Request Default

Comment: You can start by checking to see if you can increase the default timeout value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524223/what-is-the-default-response-timeout-in-jmeter and define a reasonable number

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that your server fails to respond within the bounds of the time frame JMeter waits for response

If it happens only under the load then there is nothing you can do from JMeter's side apart from setting/increasing connect and response timeouts in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults). If you leave the timeouts empty it means "no timeout" so JMeter will wait for the response forever, but underlying JVM or OS can have its own connection timeouts defined.

You can also consider [enabling debug logging for Java network](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) stack by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter instalallation)

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for JMeter HTTP components by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

in general [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) is a good troubleshooting option

Comment: Thx, Dmitri. Will there be any performance impact adding the above lines?

Comment: It will create [disk IO overhead](https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-disk-i-o-when-should-you-be-worried) due to writing massive amounts of data to the hard drive, you can check the impact by measuring it using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics). Once you figure out the root cause of connection time outs it's better to revert these configurations to default values.